# Stretching of Border's width for ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have wrote some class, named as Employe. Employees collection I set as source for ListBox WPF control. I have wrote such template for ItemTemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpEmploye">
        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Patronymic}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Post}" Foreground="Gray" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                           FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>                               
    </DataTemplate>            
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Each item has border. The border must be expanded according width of ListBox. I set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` for Border, but it is not occured as I want.

[image]

How can I correct it?

Comment: Can you please also post your ListBox XAML?

Comment: @nemesv Yes, of course: `<ListBox x:Name="lbEmployees" x:FieldModifier="internal"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmpEmploye}"/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListBox Name="lbEmployees" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmpEmploye}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 />
```